# Deducing the matrix $U^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let $u$ be an endomorphism of $\mathbb{R^2}$ with the matrix in the standard basis $B$ is :U = $\begin{bmatrix} 5&1\\-4&0\end{bmatrix}$.

1.Give the matrix $U'$ of $u$ in the basis B' = {$v1=(1,-4) , v2 = (1,-1)$}.

2.What is the transition matrix $P$ from $B$ to $B'$. Calculate $P^{-1}$

3.Deduce the matrix $U^n$ for all integer $n>2$

I've solved the first two questions and found:

$U'$=$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&4\end{bmatrix}$ , $P$=$\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\-4&-1\end{bmatrix}$ , $P^{-1}$=$\frac{1}{3}\begin{bmatrix} -1&-1\\4&1\end{bmatrix}$

But i have no idea on how to start solving the third question.

Help and hints are appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have found is that $U=P^{-1}U'P$, so that $U^n=P^{-1}U'^nP$, as the $P$s and $P^{-1}$ cancel. $U^n$ should be easy to compute.

Comment: Is $U = P^{-1}U'P$  a formula ? I haven't stumbled upon it before.

Comment: It's just a result of $P$ being a transition matrix. Perhaps drawing the diagram will help.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $PU'P^{-1}$ instead?

Comment: Let $v\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be written in $B$. $v'=Pv$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ written in $B'$. $v''=U'v'$ is the image of $v'$ under $U'$. Finally $v'''=P^{-1}v''=P^{-1}U'Pv$ is $v''$ written in $B$, which is the same as $Uv$, so $U=P{-1}U'P$.

Comment: Oh that's correect , I read the diagram backwards.